# Display driving distance between coordinates

Tags: location

I have working a site that needs mileage given between user coordinate and node coordinate. *using location module*. I thought it was returning wrong results, when I discovered it returns actual miles "as the crow flies" so to speak. I determined that when looking at what it plotted on a map. I need driving distance.

I am trying the store locator module (but it really doesn't let me do coordinates yet. But the mileage doesn't display there, and views doesn't let me do that, that I can tell.

Everything I have tried has failed. Anyone doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [The Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

If you want it to display in views there are a few ways you can implement it Either as a custom module, theme the view, or use the [views php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to show the actual driving distance between two points then you can use below code :-

function MY_MODULE_views_post_execute(&$view) {

```
  if ($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME' ) {

    //sort by driving road distance
    $results = $view->result;
    $nids = array();
    foreach($results as $node){
        $nids[] = $node->nid;
    }

    $nodes = _get_geo_position_value($nids); //gets geofield value as view result doesnt have the value

    if(count($nodes) > 0){
        $http_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial';
        $origin_text = "&origins=".$_COOKIE['currentLat'].",".$_COOKIE['currentLong']; //current location of user
        $destination_origin = '&destinations=';
         foreach($nodes as $node){

             $lat = $node->field_gmap_position['und'][0]['lat'];
             $lon = $node->field_gmap_position['und'][0]['lon'];
             $str = $lat.','.$lon.'|';

             $destination_origin.=$str;
            // $destination_origin.= $destination_origin.$node->field_gmap_position['und'][0]['lat'].','.$node->field_gmap_position['und'][0]['lon'].'|';
         }

         $destination_origin = rtrim($destination_origin, "|"); //remove trailing |


         $URL = $http_url.$origin_text.$destination_origin;

         //  Initiate curl
        $ch = curl_init();
        // Disable SSL verification
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        // Will return the response, if false it print the response
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        // Set the url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
        // Execute
        $json_output=curl_exec($ch);
        // Closing
        curl_close($ch);

        // Will dump a beauty json :3
        $calc_dist = json_decode($json_output, true);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++){
            $results[$i]->field_google_calc_dist = $calc_dist['rows'][0]['elements'][$i]['distance']['value'];
        }
        //sort by google calculated distance
        usort($results, function($a, $b)
            {

                if ($a->field_google_calc_dist == $b->field_google_calc_dist) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return ($a->field_google_calc_dist > $b->field_google_calc_dist) ? 1 : -1;
            });


    }

    $view->result = $results;

  }
```

}